# Remove Insignificant Whitespace From Xml Document

Tags: c#, xml

I've got an xml file that contains both significant and insignificant whitespace. I would like to read this file in and write the file back out to disk, removing insignificant whitespace. When considering significant vs insignificant whitespace, I want to make sure that spaces within mixed content elements (as defined by my schema) are maintained. How can I do this using C#?

Based on [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6f00zs65%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) that I read, it sounded like I might need to use a validating xml reader so that the reader would know which elements contain mixed content per the schema. Below is one example of some code I tried that did not maintain significant whitespace between elements within a parent element containing mixed content.

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.PreserveWhitespace = true;
using (XmlTextReader rdr = new XmlTextReader(xmlFilePath1))
{
    rdr.WhitespaceHandling = WhitespaceHandling.Significant;
    XmlSchemaSet sc = new XmlSchemaSet();
    sc.Add(null, @"C:\my-schema.xsd");
    doc.Load(XmlReader.Create(rdr, new XmlReaderSettings() { ValidationType = System.Xml.ValidationType.Schema, Schemas = sc }));
    using (XmlTextWriter writer = new XmlTextWriter(xmlFilePath2, Encoding.UTF8))
    {
        writer.Formatting = Formatting.None;
        doc.Save(writer);
    }
}
```

Below is an example of xml where I would like to maintain whitespace. I am expecting the whitespace between the two inline tag elements to be maintained. Para is defined in the schema as having mixed content.

```
<para>i have a bunch of text here with some <inlinetag attrib="a"/> <inlinetag attrib="b"/></para>
```

Here is a simple example of whitespace that I would want to remove. In this example, the markup came from a printy printed xml document with tabs or spaces in front of elements and line breaks after them. I would want to keep the whitespace inside the para but not outside of it.

```
  <entry colname="col2">
    <para>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, et nulla diam.<inlineTag value="a"/> <inlineTag value="b"/></para>
  </entry>
```

Comment: Which whitespaces do you want to remove then? Could you paste a full XML that also contains the *insignificant* whitespaces?

Comment: I would try to get rid if that mixed-content tag. As you have noticed, it is at the edge of what is defined. Many tools will get it wrong.

Comment: FYI, you should not use `new XmlTextReader()` or `new XmlTextWriter()`. They have been deprecated since .NET 2.0. Use `XmlReader.Create()` or `XmlWriter.Create()` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did find a solution for writing only significant whitespace, although it necessarily as straight-forward as I had hoped. Below is some example code that borrows heavily from [Mark Fussell's blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mfussell/archive/2005/02/12/371546.aspx). The only modification that I made to his WriteShallowNode method was to remove the case statement for XmlNodeType.Whitespace. This causes insignificant whitespace to be removed from the output.

```
using (var xwModifiedXml = XmlWriter.Create(xmlFilePath1))
{
    using (var sr = new StringReader(File.ReadAllText(xmlFilePath2)))
    {
        XmlSchemaSet sc = new XmlSchemaSet();
        sc.Add(null, @"C:\my-schema.xsd");
        using (var xrModifiedXml = XmlReader.Create(sr, new XmlReaderSettings() { ValidationType = System.Xml.ValidationType.Schema, Schemas = sc }))
        {
            bool readResult = xrModifiedXml.Read();
            while (readResult)
            {
                WriteShallowNode(xrModifiedXml, xwModifiedXml);
                readResult = xrModifiedXml.Read();
            }
        }
    }
}

static void WriteShallowNode( XmlReader reader, XmlWriter writer )
{
      if ( reader == null )
      {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("reader");
      }
      if ( writer == null )
      {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("writer");
      }

      switch ( reader.NodeType )
      {
            case XmlNodeType.Element:
                  writer.WriteStartElement( reader.Prefix, reader.LocalName, reader.NamespaceURI );
                  writer.WriteAttributes( reader, true );
                  if ( reader.IsEmptyElement )
                  {
                        writer.WriteEndElement();
                  }
                  break;
            case XmlNodeType.Text:
                  writer.WriteString( reader.Value );
                  break;
            case XmlNodeType.SignificantWhitespace:
                  // only write significant whitespace
                  writer.WriteWhitespace(reader.Value);
                  break;
            case XmlNodeType.CDATA:
                  writer.WriteCData( reader.Value );
                  break;
            case XmlNodeType.EntityReference:
                  writer.WriteEntityRef(reader.Name);
                  break;
            case XmlNodeType.XmlDeclaration:
            case XmlNodeType.ProcessingInstruction:
                  writer.WriteProcessingInstruction( reader.Name, reader.Value );
                  break;
            case XmlNodeType.DocumentType:
                  writer.WriteDocType( reader.Name, reader.GetAttribute( "PUBLIC" ), reader.GetAttribute( "SYSTEM" ), reader.Value );
                  break;
            case XmlNodeType.Comment:
                  writer.WriteComment( reader.Value );
                  break;
            case XmlNodeType.EndElement:
                  writer.WriteFullEndElement();
                  break;
      }
}
```